# Jetpack compose Google Maps does not load properly when using bottom navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have been stuck on this all day. I am using the official jetpack compose google maps composable. The map is displayed on one tab of my bottom navigation.

I have turned on save state and restore state when navigating

```
HomeBottomNavigation(
                        selectedNavigation = currentSelectedItem,
                        onNavigationSelected = { selected ->
                            if (selected.route != currentSelectedItem.route) {
                                navController.navigate(selected.route) {
                                    launchSingleTop = true
                                    restoreState = true

                                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                        saveState = true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    )
```

[Photo of my Bottom Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Dyo.jpg)

The problem is when navigating through the bottom navigation quickly. Meaning when I switch fast pages it will not load the map properly. I tried it also on a AndroidView Interop API approach the same thing happens. Please help really dont have an idea why this happens

Here is a [video demo](https://streamable.com/5afh9a)

Comment: I am stuck with same issue. Have you got any solution?

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace accompanying this problem? There is a known (ignored) Maps issue that I think is commonly triggered when things change fast. I can't find it right now, but if you do have a stacktrace, search the Maps issue tracker for your error.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228091313

Answer (score 0):

There was an [issue](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/112) that was causing that problem, but it has been fixed on version 2.2.1.